# How to find all finite fields in which a given polynomial has no root.

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Assume that a polynomial $p(x)$ is given. I am wondering if we may find all prime finite fields in which $p(x)$ has no root. For example if $p(x)=-x^6+3 x^5-6 x^4+7 x^3-6 x^2+3 x-1$, then $F_{11}$ is a such field. Thank you!

Comment: A finite field  of order $q=p^n$ is the splitting field of $x^q-x$. Compute the resultant of $x^q-x$ and $p(x)$?

Comment: You can enumerate all these fields by evaluating $p$ over the integers. However, that is not a characterization of all primes that work but rather an algorithm that will, eventually, reach the prime you are interested in.

Comment: @Bernard Did you mean the gcd as opposed to the resultant? Well, either one will do!

Comment: a difficult question...

Comment: @Bernard: So if the resultant is non-zero then the field of order $q=p^n$ is a such field? By Maple software, I got that $F_3,F_5,F_{11}, F_{17}, F_{23}, \cdots$ are such fields corresponding to the polynomial $p(x)=-x^6+3x^5+7x^3-6x^2+3x-1$. Do you have any idea if we need to find all  prime finite fields with that property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example polynomial
$$p(x) = -x^6 + 3 x^5 - 6 x^4 + 7 x^3 - 6 x^2 + 3 x - 1=-(x^2-x+1)^3,$$
so for this particular polynomial it is easy to give a general answer. This is because the quadratic $x^2-x+1$ is the sixth cyclotomic polynomial. It has the obvious double root $x=-1$ modulo $p=3$. Otherwise it has zeros in the prime field $K=\Bbb{F}_p$ if and only $K$ has sixth roots of unity, which happens if and only if $p\equiv1\pmod 6$.

In general, for a random polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefficients, this is a difficult question. If we know the Galois group $G$ of $f(x)$ as a group of permutations of roots of $f$, then Chebotarev's density theorem gives us a method for finding the fraction of primes for which there are modular zeros. But, in general the set of such primes won't be given by congruence conditions. That happens only (at least that's how I understand the situation) when the group $G$ is abelian. Class field theory has a lot to say about that.

Comment: My admiration flies out to you for your recognition of this polynomial as a cube.

Comment: @Lubin In that case I can confess that I took advantage of the polynomial being palindromic. So I started writing $x^3p(1/x)$ in terms of the new variable $t=x+\dfrac1x$. I wanted to find its Galois group to see if it would happen to be abelian! Then that came out. I am also known for using Mathematica more often than I should.